# Angular Signals - Using mutate() vs. Using forEach() Reactivity

Tags: angular, signals, angular-signals

Considering the following **Angular Signals** example, I'm somewhat confused about when I should use the Signal API, like *mutate()* and *update()*, when the Array API, such as *forEach*, is sufficient to trigger reactivity and update the UI/template? What is the difference here? Used Angular Version: 16.0.1

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    {{usersList() | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  usersList: Signal<any> = inject(UserService).getUsersList();
  constructor() {
 
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
  private users = signal([
    { id: 1, name: 'Peter', country: 'USA' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Party Boy', country: 'USA' },
    { id: 3, name: 'John Connor', country: 'USA' },
  ]);

  constructor() {
      window.setTimeout(()=>{
        this.changeUsersListWithoutMutate();
      }, 3000),

      window.setTimeout(()=>{
        this.changeUsersListWithMutate();
      }, 5000)
  }

  changeUsersListWithoutMutate(){
    this.users().forEach((item) => {
      if (item.id === 1) {
        item.name = "changeListWithoutMutate";
      }
    });
  }

  changeUsersListWithMutate(){
    this.users.mutate((data) => {
      data.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.id === 1) {
          item.name = "changeListWithMutate";
        }
      });
    });
  }

  getUsersList() {
    return this.users;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would add that anytime you can directly manipulate a signal using the signal API, do it there. Anything else has the chance to inadvertently trigger change detection somewhere else and when you can limit changes to only the precise piece that you want, that is almost always going to be the better solution.

Comment: Here is StackBlitz with your code, but just 1 line is added: "changeDetection: OnPush": https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bdcac1?file=src%2Fmain.ts
You can see that because of this line, you will only see the second modification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are observing in your example is standard change detection because you rely on `setTimeout()`.

`setTimeout` is one of the APIs patched by `zone.js`, this means everytime it's called Angular will fire a change detection cycle and refresh your DOM. Since the value wraped by the signal has been changed (no matter which way), the new value will appear in the DOM.

That being said, back to the signal basics:

In `changeUsersListWithoutMutate`, you're not updating the signal because you're reading its value and changing its nested values. The signal itself has no way to know it has been updated.

This is why `changeUsersListWithMutate` is the way to go. You're explicitly telling the signal that you are updating it's value and the signal will fire the change detection.

Let me know if something isn't clear in my answer.

Comment: But what is the recommendation if I want to use Signals for the Change Detection? Should all components then be activating the .onPush strategy?

Comment: Yes you might see some differences if you use OnPush but keep in mind that the full signal integration is not ready yet (I'm talking about signal components and zoneless apps)